# iPhone + picture share + picture host

Tags: iphone, facebook

I wrote an app for iPhone which lets you create a picture (kind of like photoshop). I wanted to let people share their pictures via Facebook for example, however their API only allows you to show images in a user's news feed via an image URL (you can't first upload a local image to the facebook servers and host it from there). It looks something like:

> "Hey checkout what I made: ", "http://somesite.com/myimage.png"

I was thinking of creating an account at a site like photobucket.com, and whenever a user shares a picture in my app, I first upload it to the picture site, then use that url. I have a feeling that would somehow violate terms of use.

I could get an unlimited hosting account to store the pictures (like at godaddy) but don't think it would really scale very well as I'm sure an unlimited account really does have limits, just not advertised too well. Any suggestions on how I could get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can most defently upload your images to Facebook, look at the API more closely, and check out Facebook Connect for iphone http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone and here is the link for the  API call to upload pictures http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Photos.upload

Comment: how would that work? Would each user upload to their own facebook account? What if they user don't have a facebook account? I think the author wants a central photo hosting service. I'm looking for a solution to this also.

Comment: well ofcourse one would need a face book account, the asker said he can only upload to the feed, which i am assuming means that the user of the app already would need to have facebook. For a solution where one would not need to sign up or have some sort o f user  id then how would the service know what pictures to show a user when they want to see their own pictures? does not make since not to have some sort of user account in this case.

Comment: If you want to make a service that can just host pictures then the only problem is to find a host for your service, writting the code f or t he service and talking to it through iphone is cake. Windows  Azure provides a good solution for hosting needs (theres other similar cloud services out there as well)

Comment: Hmm yeah basically I'm trying to mimic the functionality of the "what's on your mind?" tool in Facebook when you login as a normal user. You can write some text, then 'attach' a picture, from local disk.

It looks like when I do that, the picture with the image is uploaded from local disk to my "Photos" collection. So maybe the correct call to make is Photos.upload as suggested.

This seems to be different than the news feed template which is the default implementation in the facebook-connect sample project? In that case, it only accepts image urls. Am I right on this?

Thanks

Comment: I dont know but you can  use facebook connect to upload pictures as well